# Can I connect my component to a particular node in the store based on props parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

My redux store looks like this:

```
"products":[
  {
    "product-id":"P1",
    "product-name":"Computer"
  },
  {
    "product-id":"P2",
    "product-name":"Monitor"
  },
  {
    "product-id":"P3",
    "product-name":"Keyboard"
  },
  {
    "product-id":"P4",
    "product-name":"Mouse"
  }
]
```

Now I have a component that get's the Product ID as props. Is there a way to map the state to props based in the Product ID? For eg: if props.product_id="P2", then I want to map only to the "product-id":"P2" node to the component props.

I might be getting this wrong as we use connect() to connect to the whole store but I want to keep mapStateToProps lean (not sure if that even makes sense).

Thanks.

Comment: Since one way or another, you store all the data in redux. There may be no difference to filter in components as soon as you acquire them from redux.

Answer (score 1):

You can you ownProps which is optional parameter in mapStateToProps (Reference: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#ownprops-optional)

then your code will look something like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const { products } = state
  const { product_id } = ownProps
  const filteredProduct = products.find(({product-id}) => product-id ===product_id)

  return { filteredProduct }
}
```